# Handling NoneType or empty list indices when iterating through variable lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a function `measure_amount()` that returns a dict inside a list with a specific 'total' amount from an obj if the amount exists. Example:

```
[{'unit': 'foo', 'total': Decimal('5900.00'), 'type': None}]
```

When iterating through measurement on multiple objects, the dict-in-list is variable and there may or may not be a 'total' or the list may be empty. Sometimes the function willreturn an empty list:

```
[]
```

My original code was:

```
for o in objects:
    l = o.measure_amount()
    # use enumerate to get the index for 'total' if it exists
    i = next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(l) if d["total"]), None)
    amount = l[i]["total"]
    total_amount += amount

return total_amount
```

This works for when "total" exists in the index but throws an err when the list is empty because in the index is None:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

I can use an `if` statement to check `if i is not None:` as a condition before `amount = l[i]["total"]` but I'm wondering from a pythonic perspective - is there a better way to handle this type of list variability? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use exceptions, in the spirit on Python's: ask for forgiveness, not for permission.

```
for o in objects:
    l = o.measure_amount()
    try:
        # use enumerate to get the index for 'total' if it exists
        i = next((index for (index, d) in enumerate(l) if d["total"]), None)
        amount = l[i]["total"]
        total_amount += amount
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        pass

return total_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) on the `total` key with a default value of `Decimal(0)` for each dictionary in `l`, and then just `sum` the results:

```py
l = [
 {'unit': 'bar', 'type': None},
 {'unit': 'foo', 'total': Decimal('5900.00'), 'type': None}
]
sum(d.get('total', Decimal(0)) for d in l)
```

Output:

```
Decimal('5900.00')
```